# Substitute windows cmd

Tags: windows, cmd

I found PowerCmd. And would like to substiture cmd - as default IDE for execution of bat files.
But simple replacin of comspec do nothing.
I cann't also rename cmd.exe in %SYSTEM32%.
Is possible to substiture or not?
Thanks.

Comment: You can define default program for your .bat extension. Just right click on .bat file and Open with -> Choose default program ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I am giving answer for Powershell, should be similar for anything else that you want to use**:

Use Regedit and goto

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\open\command
```

Set the default value to

`C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noexit "%1" %*`

Now when you double click on any batch file, it should run on powershell. `-noexit` gets to the powershell prompt after completion of the batch file.